# How Hibernate flushes in details

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I could't find information how Hibernates flush method actually works under the hood. What I found is the information that "flush method synchronize persistance object with the underlaying DB", but how does it look in details?
I'm using Java JPA with Hibernate implementation.
Let's assume we have got an object User with fields

```
public class User{
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private UserStatus status;
private Double longitude;
private Double latitude;
}
```

We have got a method "A" which is @Transactional.
 In the beginning we read that object from DB and
based on his status we would like to update his coordinates (`longiture`/`latitude`) with current values or not. We set new coordinates.
There the main part of posts question comes in.
What I know is, when transaction is completed, current object state is flushed and commited. But how hibernate synchronize that object? Does he check "field by field" if particular field value is the same as in column, or he "remember" if we have used SETTER on field?
Question is important when another transactional method "B" wants to update `firstName` of the same user object.
Let's consider example:

1. Method A starts and read object values from DB
2. Method B starts and read the same object from DB
3. Method A update user `firstName` and end transaction
4. Method B update user `coordinates` and end transaction

What happened than? Will method B overrid firstName in the DB while persistance values are different than in DB but never touched by this method? Or only coordinates will by updated while only them were touched.

Comment: Why not try it out? You could possibly run into a `StaleStateException` when a second transaction tries to save an "outdated" version of the "same" object as a first transaction.

Comment: What [locking strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking) do you use?

Comment: Will method B overrid firstName in the DB. Yes. See OptimisticLocking where update B would fail at flush time as entity verison has been updated by A. See also @DynamicUpdate https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamicupdate where only changed fields would be updated in DB.

Comment: Maybe stupid question but do I need to use any of strategies by default? I didn't set anything, and looking how my system behaves - one transaction B which is called later overrides commited data by previous method A (only explanation which I figured out).

Comment: @AlanHay Thank you for response and explain what I asked in details. It's good to know but in my case, that entity is used quite often so it will cause a lot of little calls to DB.